# On Clean Architecture, Should Entity represent plural and singular?

Tags: software-design, clean-architecture

Wondering about this because for instance, if I have Entity User and Users, If im understanding correctly about Single responsibility principle I should seperate them? my methods may sepearate policies for db interface of methods that affect a single user or multiple user...

i.e. rough example:

```js
interface UserDb {
  createUser()
  getUserById()
  deleteSingleUser()
}

interface UsersDb {
  deleteMultipleUsers()
  flagMultipleUser()
}

interface UserObj {
  id: string
  reportedFlag: boolean
  createdOn: string
  hashedPassword: string
  name: string
}

class User {

  #dbAccessor: UserDb;
  constructor(dbAccessor) {
  #dbAccessor = dbAccessor;
}

  createNewUser(email, hashedpw) {
    this.#dbAccessor.createUser(email, hashedpw)
  }

 // ...
}

class Users {

  #dbAccessor: UsersDb;
  constructor(dbAccessor) {
  #dbAccessor = dbAccessor;
}

  flagUsers(userIdArr) {
  this.#dbAccessor.flagMultipleUsers(userIdArr)
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can, but most places don't. Single responsibility is mostly just seen for the type of Entity. For example I have a class OrderService which has the methods: place(order: Order) and place(orders : List[Order]).

It's more about not mixing for example logic of the Costumer and the Order so that when anything changes anywhere it changes in only ONE place and doesn't directly (mostly) affect other logic.

Seperating single and plural implementations will only add an extra place to check for logic.

Comment: Thank you Jurgen - makes sense ! and is OrderService a use case here?  if you don't mind, could you give a shot answering my latest question about the border between entity and use-cases?

Comment: Do you mean as in objects and services using certain objects? Sorry my english is good, but sometimes not as good as I wish... If the question is if you should seperate for example the Order (the object holding all the information) and the OrderService (the service using order objects to for example put them in a table, or assign them to a Customer, etc...) then yes separate them.

I like working like this (but whatever you prefer): DTO (what is sent over the web), DatabaseEntity (what is saved in the database) , Repository (the db) , Service, Mapper, etc...